# Generate Alternative when Unique Index fails on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, oauth, coffeescript

So when users sign up via Google, Twitter or such, names can overlap. Within my app, usernames have a unique index. Since a new document is put into the collection whenever someone signs in for the first time, sometimes the unique index fails. The code for signing up a user goes like this:

```
module.exports.findOrCreateUser = (provider, id, data, done) ->
    User.findByAuth provider, id, (err, user) ->
        if err? then done err
        else if user? then done null, user
        else
            user = new User
                auth: [{id: id, provider: provider}]
                name: data.name
                email: data.email
            user.save (err) ->
                if err? then done err else done null, user
```

So I have two problems here:

1. How can I check if `err` is a unique index error?
2. What is the most efficient way to append an unique suffix to the user's name?

Comment: What about prefixing/suffixing it by the service the user used to login. For example google_username, twitter_username, facebook_username, ...

Comment: For Q(1), I am sure the `err` should contain a error code along with a descriptive message something like "duplicate key error index". You should log the `err` once, to know that.

Comment: @innoSPG: That's a great idea. I never thought of that. Though I wanted to avoid an indication of the service they used to sign in with...

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Unfortunately I was not able to find out any documentation on the error format/codes of `node-mongodb-native`, perhaps you have something?

Comment: I guess this code is executed at the server side. Also, I suggested you to log the error for once to know the actual error. In the mongo shell you get this error `E11000 duplicate key error index: test.test2.$a_1  dup key: { : 1.0 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `err` object has a `message` attribute that matches the error message the mongo shell would give. Checking if there's a unique index error should look something like this:

   ```
   if (err && err.message.indexOf('E11000 ') !== -1) {
       // this _id was already inserted in the database
   }
   ```
2. I agree with @innoSPG to append the service name to username. If you don't want indication of the service associated with the username just append a counter to the username and increment it every time it's used.